# XSLT - add dynamically changing attribute based on position

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml file like this,

```
<doc>
    <lo>
        <li>text1</li>
        <li>text2</li>
        <li>text3</li>
        <li>text4</li>
        <li>text5</li>
        <li>text6</li>
        <li>text7</li>
        <li>text8</li>
        <li>text9</li>
        <li>text10</li>
        <li>text11</li>
        <li>text12</li>
        <li>text13</li>
        <li>text14</li>
        <li>text15</li>
        <li>text16</li>
    </lo>
</doc>
```

I need to dynamically add `padding` attribute to the list items. sequence of adding `padding` is staring from 25 each multipliers  5 should add padding value by detriment sequence.

eg:

```
5th list item: padding=25
10th list item: padding=20
15th list item: padding=15
10th list item: padding=10
```

and for each first preceding sibling and following sibling of 5th multipliers shold get the padding value -3 from the middle 5th multipliers.

eg:

```
4th list item: padding=22
5th list item: padding=25
6th list item: padding=22
9th list item: padding=17
10th list item: padding=20
11th list item: padding=17
```

So sample expected output should look like this,

```
<doc>
    <lo>
        <li>text1</li>
        <li>text2</li>
        <li>text3</li>
        <li padding ="22">text4</li>
        <li padding ="25">text5</li>
        <li padding ="22">text6</li>
        <li>text7</li>
        <li>text8</li>
        <li padding ="17">text9</li>
        <li padding ="20">text10</li>
        <li padding ="17">text11</li>
        <li>text12</li>
        <li>text13</li>
        <li padding ="12">text14</li>
        <li padding ="15">text15</li>
        <li padding ="12">text16</li>
    </lo>
</doc>
```

I have written following xslt for do this task,

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li">
        <li>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="(abc:get-list-position(.) mod 5) =0">
                    <xsl:attribute name="padding" select="25"/>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="abc:get-list-position">
        <xsl:param name="node"/>

        <xsl:sequence select="count($node/preceding-sibling::li) + 1"/>
    </xsl:function>
```

But since XSLT does not have incremental variables and advance loops, I'm struggling to further extend my logic. Can any one suggest me how can I achieve this task using XSLT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT already has a `position()` function, there is no need for you to reinvent it.

AFAICT, you want to do:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="li[position() gt 3 and position() mod 5 = (0, 1, 4)]">
    <xsl:variable name="x" select="6 - (position() + 1) idiv 5" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="padding" select="5 * $x - 3 * number(position() mod 5 != 0)"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```